# How are shockwaves used to study magnetic fields of merging galaxy clusters?

Tags: galaxy, radio-astronomy, galaxy-cluster, radio, merger

Recently i read an article about how a shockwave 60 times larger than milky way galaxy is generated.When these shockwaves interacts with magnetic field, radio waves are emitted. I wanted to know how these radio waves are used to study the magnetic field lines of the merging galaxy clusters?

Here is the link for website -
https://scitechdaily.com/astronomers-see-an-enormous-shockwave-60x-bigger-than-the-entire-milky-way-galaxy/

Comment: It sounds interesting; could you please add a link to the article you've recently read, or at least a citation? Thanks, and *Welcome to Astronomy!*

Comment: Yup! I edited it